# Check if Query in sqlite is empty in a bindView method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

How to check if data queried from android `sqlite` database is empty in a bindView method?

This is what I have done so far, but I think I am doing the wrong thing.

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

     SQLiteDatabase db;

        db = openOrCreateDatabase(
            "no.db"
            , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
            , null
            );
      //CREATE TABLES AND INSERT MESSAGES INTO THE TABLES
        String CREATE_TABLE_NOTICES = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notices ("
                + "ID INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NOT TEXT,"
                + "DA TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTICES);

        Cursor myCur = null;
   // SQLiteDatabase db;
    myCur = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID as _id,NOT,DA FROM notices order by ID desc", null);


    mListAdapter = new MyAdapter(Page.this, myCur);
    setListAdapter(mListAdapter);

}

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor myCur) {
        TextView firstLine=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

        if(myCur==null){
                String message="No Message";
                firstLine.setText(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please can anybody help me with my problem above?

Comment: You think you're doing the wrong thing - why?  What's the problem?

Comment: I think I am doing the wrong thing because It doesnt seem to work wen executed, it doesnt give an error too in the logcat

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  That's a great way to figure out exactly what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword **`NOT`** is a reserved word in MySQL. I'd be very surprised if it's not a reserved word in SQLite.

I think the problem is here:

```
  SELECT ID as _id,NOT,DA FROM notices order by ID desc
  --               ^^^
```

It looks like the reserved word **`NOT`** is being used as a column name. To use that as an identifier, it will need to be "escaped", by enclosing it in backtick characters.

```
  SELECT ID as _id,`NOT`,DA FROM notices ORDER BY ID DESC
  --               ^   ^
```

That's the normative pattern in MySQL. For SQLite, you use the (MySQL compatible ) backtick characters, or you can use double quotes (more ANSI standard compliant.)

It's also possible to qualify the column name. (I'm certain this works in MySQL).

```
  SELECT n.ID AS `_id`, n.NOT, n.DA FROM notices n ORDER BY n.id DESC
  --     ^^             ^^     ^^                ^          ^^
```

---

References:

MySQL Reference Manual: [**9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

> Certain keywords, such as `SELECT`, `DELETE`, or `BIGINT`, are *reserved* and require special treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names.

SQLite: [**SQLite Keywords** https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:

---

It may also be a problem in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Since you are creating the table, you have the option of using a different name for the column, a name which is *not* a reserved word.

Comment: I am able to query out my data, although I have added the the backtick. My problem is how do I print out a message on the activity when my query returns null or is equal to 0. I am sorry if i wasnt clear with my question above. Thanks